# SQL: select last pay time with money in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called "pay_logs", including user's payment logs,

### 1. Fields as followed:

================================================

```
id           | primary key, auto_increment
user_account | NOT NULL, NOT UNIQUE
money        | DEFAULT 0.00
time         | NOT NULL
```

================================================

### 2. Data in table

================================================

```
id | user_account | time | money
1 | Mary | 1480000008 | 10.00
2 | Mary | 1480000009 | 5.00
3 | John | 1480000001 | 2.00
4 | John | 1480000002 | 1.00
```

================================================

And I'd like to select user's **LAST pay time with its money**,
so how can I do this in one SQL

Here is my SQL

```
select *, max(time)
from pay_logs
group by user_account;
```

### 3. And it's result:

================================================

```
id | user_account | time | money | max(time)
3 | John | 1480000001 | 2.00 | 1480000002
1 | Mary | 1480000008 | 10.00 | 1480000009
```

================================================

### 4. But it won't work as my wish:

**What data I want is records with id 2 and 4**,
so any one help me? I want to do this in one SQL, just SQL,
if SQL falied to do this job, any other solutions? THX TXH TXH ~~~

P.S.I am using PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your query as a basis, you need to use `group by` and a `join`:

```
select pl.*
from pay_logs pl join
     (select user_account, max(time) as maxt
      from pay_logs
      group by user_account
     ) ua
     on pl.user_account = ua.user_account and pl.time = ua.maxt;
```

Your query uses a MySQL (mis)feature that allows columns in the `group by` that are not in the `group by` clause.  Unless you *really* know what you are doing, you should never do this.

Comment: but your SQL fail to select records as my wish.

Comment: You should get rid of the max(time) in your first select for query to work properly.

Comment: Your welcome. Little explanation on my previous comment if someone will be reading, if you select max(time) in your first query, the result will consist of one row only - with the largest time value. Anyway, because you are still selecting everything, you will get max(time) in your result as column maxt. Also you should correct us.maxt to ua.maxt as @yip pointed out.

Comment: can u write the SQL? I can't understand. THX